# Tezos mempool track info

Tags: node, tezos-client, tezos-signer

Could someone describe if there is a way to track and get transactions informations like Tx signature, hash ... from tezos mempool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/mempool/pending_operations
(same but less overhead) http://127.0.0.1:8732/chains/main/mempool/pending_operations
```

Output is a JSON object. Just parse it using your favorite programming language.

Comment: @Khaled Please mark question as answered